# Running js function on table

Tags: javascript

How do I make it change each element to a random color instead of changing all the elements to the same random color

```
function RandomColor() {
const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for (i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    x = th[i]
x.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of declaring a constant value for `randomColor` outside the loop, you can generate a new `randomColor` for each iteration of the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the random color in the iteration so it resets for every element.

```js
function RandomColor() {
  var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  for (i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    x = th[i]
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  }
}

RandomColor();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Lorem</th>
    <th>Ipsum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```